Unable to send a POST form data in python
I am trying to use Python default library http.client to send a form-data. The reason is that I am unable to install other packages like requests on the system and it does not have even the urllib3.
Python code here
import http.client
import uuid

def send_email_http_only(from_email, reply_to, send_to, subject, mail_content, filename, attachment_path):
    # Prepare the file content
    file_path = attachment_path
    with open(file_path, "rb") as f:
        file_content = f.read()

    # Define boundary and headers
    boundary = str(uuid.uuid4())
    headers = {
        "User-Agent": f"MyApp/1.0",
        "Content-Type": f"multipart/form-data; boundary=----{boundary}",
    }

    # Create HTTP connection
    conn = http.client.HTTPConnection("localhost", 8088)

    # Create multipart/form-data payload
    payload = (
        # f"----{boundary}\r\n"
        # f"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"attachment\"; filename=\"" + filename + "\"\r\n"
        # f"{file_content.decode('utf-8')}\r\n"
        f"----{boundary}\r\n"
        f"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"emailContent\"\r\n"
        f"Content-Type: application/json\r\n\r\n"
        f"{{\"replyTo\": \""+reply_to+"\", \"from\": \""+from_email+"\", \"sendTo\": \""+send_to+"\", \"subject\": \""+subject+"\", \"mailContent\": \""+mail_content+"\"}\r\n"
        f"----{boundary}--\r\n"
    )

    emailContent = {
        'replyTo': reply_to,
        'from': from_email,
        'sendTo': send_to,
        'subject': subject,
        'mailContent': mail_content
    }

    # print(f"request_data: {request_data}")
    # print(f"payload: {payload}")
    # print(f"headers: {headers}")

    # Send the request
    conn.request("POST", "/sendEmail", body=payload, headers=headers)

    # Get the response
    response = conn.getresponse()
    data = response.read()

    # Close the connection
    conn.close()

    # Print response
    print("Program response:")
    print(response.status, response.reason)
    print(data.decode("utf-8"))

After running this method, I keep getting bad request "emailContent" is not present.
I have also tried adding http.client.HTTPConnection.debuglevel = 1 but the output does not look invalid.
send: b'POST /sendEmail HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: localhost:8088\r\nAccept-Encoding: identity\r\nContent-Length: 340\r\nUser-Agent: MyApp/1.0\r\nContent-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----18e9255e-7597-42ef-814f-f10b4f0a2c6e\r\n\r\n'
send: b'----18e9255e-7597-42ef-814f-f10b4f0a2c6e\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="emailContent"\r\nContent-Type: application/json\r\n\r\n{"replyTo": "x@gmail.com", "from": "y@outlook.com", "sendTo": "y@outlook.com", "subject": "Test subject", "mailContent": "Test main content"}\r\n----18e9255e-7597-42ef-814f-f10b4f0a2c6e--\r\n'
reply: 'HTTP/1.1 400 \r\n'

Appreciate any help here :)

you really should use requests or urlib3, you can always install it on another system and then copy over the dependency files to site-packages of the target system.

You never use the emailContent dictionary.

Don't try to create JSON using string formatting. Use json.dumps()
